# Updatating html rows using jstl

Tags: java, mysql, jstl

hi i have table like this

```
id   pname   quanity  Action
-----------------------------
1    mouse      1   update
2    keyboard   2   update
3    monitor    3   update
```

I want to update table after clicking on click on update

I have written a code using JSTL tags.. but it's updating only first row .
I am very new to jstl can anyone help me out?

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dbsource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample" user="root" password="sample" />
<sql:query dataSource="${dbsource}" var="result"> SELECT * from product ; </sql:query>

<form action="#" method="post">
<table border="0" width="40%">
    <caption>Update Product</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" value="${row.id}" name="id"/>
                <input type="text" value="${row.pname}" name="pname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${row.quantity}" name="qty"/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<a href="index.jsp">Go Home</a>
</form>

<sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="count">
  UPDATE product SET pname = ?, quantity=? WHERE id='${param.id}'
  <sql:param value="${param.pname}" />
  <sql:param value="${param.qty}" />
</sql:update>
<c:if test="${count>=1}">
<font size="5" color='green'> Congratulations ! Data updated successfully.</font>
  <a href="index.jsp">Go Home</a>         
</c:if>
```